# Laravel best practice to use config variable in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this code in blade

```
if($user_type == 1) {
   // do something
}

if($user_type == 2) {
   // do something
}
```

Now this code is not good because other developer don't have an idea what is $user_type == 1 or $user_type == 2 means. I know we can create const in class and then use them but I am writing this code in blade. So is it good practice to use config variable or whats the best practice ?

Comment: "Best practice" is subjective. When Laravel is used properly, the variables are defined in the controller and passed to the view. A Laravel programmer usually knows to look in the controller functions to see what the variables are. You can use constants in the model to help define what those user types mean, but `$user_type` is just a variable, it's not attached to anything anyway. (BTW, if those two `if` statements are next to each other, the second should be an `else if`)

Comment: If you need these to "mean" something, then `== 1` and `== 2` isn't great, since 1 and 2 are non-descriptive numbers. They're probably tied to _something_, like `1: Admin`, or `2: User` (or similar), but you'd have to find that definition somewhere. You could use an Enum, like `@if($userType == UserTypeEnum::Admin->value)`, or `@if($userType == UserTypeEnum::User->value)` (or similar), or a Config value, like `@if($userType == config('constants.admin'))`, etc. There's lots of valid approaches, and there's nothing inherently wrong with your approach, but it could definitely be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The book "*Clean Code*" describes this approach and to me it seems better to use it with php8.1 enums.

```
enum UserType: string
{
    case ADMIN = 'admin' // OR '1';
    case WRITER = 'writer' // OR '2';
}
```

And then already use `UserType::Admin->value` inside the code, which will allow all developers to understand what we are talking about and easily adapt in the code. [Enums](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.basics.php) is quite flexible and will give you more use than just strings

If you are using *PHP < version 8.1*

```
class UserType 
{
    const ADMIN = 'admin' // OR '1';
    const WRITER = 'writer' // OR '2';
}
```

And then already use `UserType::ADMIN` inside the code. It's a pretty good [package](https://github.com/myclabs/php-enum)